# Docker - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf-spectacular'

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add drf_spectacular, but when I run container, I get this error:
[Error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6hak.png)

drf_spectacular is aviable on installed python package in my container:
[Installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Jpw.png)

requirements.txt

```
Django>=4.0.4,<4.1
djangorestframework>=3.13.1,<3.14
psycopg2>=2.8.6,<2.9
django-filter>=22.1,<22.2
drf-spectacular>=0.22.1,<0.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name is `drf_spectacular`, not `drf-spectacular`. See the installation docs: https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular#installation

Comment: You have saved time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The module is named drf_spectacular, you have a dash there instead of an underscore.